# how to create coturn server directly on subdomain

Tags: webrtc, turn, simplewebrtc, coturn

On my ec2 instance for CentOS, I want to create coturn server directly on my subdomain https://live.talkrecruit.com instead of live.talkrecruit.com:3478
I have already setup coturn live.talkrecruit.com:3478 but want to remove port 3478 and still make it work like simplewebrtc sandbox turn server sandbox.simplewebrtc.com

Comment: What about running coturn on port 80 or 443?
My experience showed, that the nat traversal will run a bit smoother and connections to 80/443 don't look that suspicious to some firewalls.
Give it a try :-)

Comment: how to do that, i am completely new to it, any reference would be great help

Comment: Just edit "listening-port=3478" in your turnserver.conf to 80 or 443 instead of 3478 ;)

Comment: bind: Permission denied
Cannot bind local socket to addr: Permission denied
is the error i am getting when trying to change 3478 to 80 or 443